# find ${dy}/{dx}$ if $x^y + y^x = 1$

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Find ${dy}/{dx}$ if $x^y + y^x = 1$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: The derivative, for a branch of the relation, is $0$ since $x^0+0^y=1$ for $x>\frac12$

Answer (score 5):

This may seem tricky but recall the derivatives of $2^x$ and $x^2$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(2^x)=2^x\ln(2) \quad \frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$$

Now, let's try approaching the problem.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^y)=yx^{y-1}+x^y\ln(x)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx},\qquad \frac{d}{dx}(y^x)=y^x\ln(y)+xy^{x-1}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
This may be hard to see but let's look at it another "way" (more of a physicist point of view):

*Mulitply* both sides by $dx$
$$d(x^y)=yx^{y-1}dx+x^y\ln(x)dy, \qquad d(y^x)=y^x\ln(y)dx + xy^{x-1}dy$$
As you can see, the derivative is of $x^y$ and $y^x$ is the derivative with respect to $x$ on the left side $+$ the derivative with repsect to $y$ on the right side.

So, 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(x^y\ln(x)-xy^{x-1}\right)=-(y^x\ln(y)+yx^{y-1})$$

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y^x\ln(y)+yx^{y-1}}{x^y\ln(x)-xy^{x-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no point $(x,y)$ in the first quadrant that satisfies $x^y+y^x=1$. Therefore the equation $x^y+y^x=1$ does not define implicitly a function $x\mapsto y=f(x)$, even locally.

Comment: It's clear you're right from looking at the graph of $z = \exp(x \ln y) + \exp(y \ln x), x>0, y >0$, but how does one prove analytically that there is no solution to $z= 1$?

Comment: @GFauxPas, this is because $x^y+y^x>1$ for all $x,y>0$.  It suffices to consider $0<x,y<1$.  We have $x^y>x(x+y-xy)^{-1}$ due to Bernoulli's inequality $(1-(1-x))^{1-y}<1-(1-x)(1-y)$;  similarly $y^x>y(x+y-xy)^{-1}$, i.e., $x^y+y^x>(x+y)(x+y-xy)^{-1}>1$.

Answer (score 1):

$${d\over dx}x^y=yx^{y-1}+x^y\ln(x){dy\over dx}$$$${d\over dx}y^x=y^x\ln(y)+xy^{x-1}{dy\over dx}$$

Now solve.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the real function nor accordingly its derivative can be defined. When the function itself cannot be defined its derivative by implicit differentiation is meaningless.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer.  You might consider showing the analysis behind the observation that $x^y+y^x > 1$ for all $x> 0$, $y > 0$.

Comment: The Monge plot shows it be so and presently I even cannot explain the maximum value at x=0, y=0... that I suspect should be expressed in terms of $e$.

Answer (score 0):

let denote $$F\left( x,y \right) =x^{ y }+y^{ x }-1$$ 
since  $$dF\left( x,y \right) =0\\ { F }_{ x }^{ \prime  }dx+{ F }_{ y }^{ \prime  }dy=0\\ { F }_{ x }^{ \prime  }+{ F }_{ y }^{ \prime  }\frac { dy }{ dx } =0\\ \frac { dy }{ dx } =-\frac { { F }_{ x }^{ \prime  } }{ { F }_{ y }^{ \prime  } } $$
so

> $$\frac { dy }{ dx } =-\frac { { F }_{ x }^{ \prime  } }{ { F }_{ y }^{ \prime  } } =-\frac { y{ x }^{ y-1 }+{ y }^{ x }\ln { y }  }{ x{ y }^{ x-1 }+{ x }^{ y }\ln { x }  } $$

Comment: not sure I understand your second equality

Comment: The second equality is a mistake.

Comment: where is a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

To find the derivative of function in the form $y=x^{f(x)}$, you need to know that $(\ln f(x))'= \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$, so $f'(x)=f(x)(\ln f(x))'$

Then differentiate both sides and think that $y = f(x)$ and $x$ is the independent variable, i.e. $$(x^y)'+(y^x)'=0.$$

$$(x^y)'=x^y(\ln x^y)'=x^y(y\ln x)'=x^y(y'\ln x+\frac{y}{x});\\
(y^x)'=y^x(\ln y^x)'=y^x(x\ln y)'=y^x(\ln y+x\frac{y'}{y}).
$$

So we need to pull out $y'$ from that:
$$x^y y'\ln x+x^y\frac{y}{x}+y^x\ln y+xy^x\frac{y'}{y}=0,\\
y'(x^y \ln x+\frac{xy^x}{y})=-x^y\frac{y}{x}-y^x\ln y.$$
Finally,
$$y'=-\frac{x^y\frac{y}{x}+y^x\ln y}{\frac{xy^x}{y}+x^y \ln x}.$$