# Differentiate the following function with respect to $x:$ $x^y +y^x=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate the following function with respect to $x:$

$x^y +y^x=1$

My steps:
$x^y +y^x=1$

Taking $\ln$ of both sides,we get,
$y\ln x+x\ln y=\ln 1=0$
Now,differentiating both sides with respect to $x,$ we get,
$\frac{y}{x}+\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg(\ln x+\frac{x}{y}\bigg)+\ln y=0\implies \frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{y(y+x\ln y)}{x(x+y \ln x)}.$

But the real answer is $$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{y(y^{x-1}\ln(y) + x^{y-1})}{x(x^{y-1}\ln(x) + y^{x-1})}$$

Why the real answer is different from mine?
Looks like my approach is wrong,but why?

Kindly, explain it to the core.Thank you!

Comment: How did you take that $\ln$? Note that $\ln(a+b) \neq \ln(a) + \ln(b)$...

Comment: Oh I see! By the way,would you show your approach here?

Comment: @Debrogli Welcome to Math SE. Note that $x^y = e^{\ln(x^y)} = e^{y\ln(x)}$.

Comment: Let $F(x,y)=x^y+y^x-1.$ Then, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\frac{yx^{y-1}+y^x\ln(y)}{xy^{x-1}+x^y\ln(x)}.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find ${dy}/{dx}$ if $x^y + y^x = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841662/find-dy-dx-if-xy-yx-1). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5Ey%20%2B%20y%5Ex%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Adifferentiate&p=1). FYI, there's also the quite similar [I need to find y' for y^x=x^y](/q/2033398/602049).

Comment: @John Omielan,Why the user  segregated $x$ and $y$ terms after taking $\log$ of both sides while evaluating the derivative of $x^y=y^x$ w.r.t $x?$

Comment: @Debrogli I assume you're referring to the second post I linked to, in particular this [answer](/a/2033424). If so, it's done to make it simpler & easier to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$. In particular, for any differentiable function $f(y)$, note that using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) gives $\frac{d(f(y))}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d(f(y)}{dy}$. In this case, we have $f(y) = \frac{\log y - 1}{(\log y)^2}$.

Comment: @John Omielan, couldn't we just take $\log$ of both sides in $x^y=y^x\implies y\log x=x\log y?$ And then differentiate both sides separately to get the $y'?$

Comment: @Debrogli Yes, that's also valid. However, you then have $\frac{dy}{dx}$ on both sides of the equation, possibly making it a bit more complicated than what's shown in that answer. Note that with that problem, like almost all math problems, there is more than one way to solve it. The "best" way for a particular person depends on factors like what technique(s) are (un)known, the complexity involved, how easy it's to understand, its length, etc.

Comment: John Omielan,here is my try: $x^y=y^x.$ Taking $\log$ of both sides,we get $y\log x=x\log y.$ Now, differentiating both sides separately w r.t $x,$ we get, $\frac{y}{x}+\log x\times \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}\times \frac{dy}{dx}+\log y\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}\bigg(\frac{x\log y-y}{y\log x-x}\bigg).$ Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have
$$ x^y+y^x=1,$$
we can say that given $x$, we must have $\operatorname{y}(x)$ s.t:

$$x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}+(\operatorname{y}(x))^x=1$$

We implicitly differentiate wrt $x$:
$$
0=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\right)+\dfrac{d}{dx}\left((\operatorname{y}(x))^{x}\right)
$$

Let $u= x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}$, we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln u&=& \operatorname{y}(x)\ln x\\
\dfrac{1}{u}\dfrac{du}{dx}&=&\dfrac{\operatorname{y}(x)}{x}+\operatorname{y}'(x)\ln x\\
\dfrac{du}{dx}&=&x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{y}(x)}{x}+\operatorname{y}'(x)\ln x\right)\\
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\right)&=&x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{y}(x)}{x}+\operatorname{y}'(x)\ln x\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Let $t=(\operatorname{y}(x))^x$, we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln t&=&x\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))\\
\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{dt}{dx}&=&\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))+\dfrac{x\operatorname{y}'(x)}{\operatorname{y}(x)}\\
\dfrac{dt}{dx}&=&(\operatorname{y}(x))^x\left(\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))+\dfrac{x\operatorname{y}'(x)}{\operatorname{y}(x)}\right)\\
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left((\operatorname{y}(x))^{x}\right)&=&(\operatorname{y}(x))^x\left(\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))+\dfrac{x\operatorname{y}'(x)}{\operatorname{y}(x)}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

So we finally get:
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\right)+\dfrac{d}{dx}\left((\operatorname{y}(x))^{x}\right)\\
0&=&x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{y}(x)}{x}+\operatorname{y}'(x)\ln x\right)+(\operatorname{y}(x))^x\left(\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))+\dfrac{x\operatorname{y}'(x)}{\operatorname{y}(x)}\right)\\
0&=&\operatorname{y}'(x)\left(x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\ln x+x(\operatorname{y}(x))^{x-1}\right)+\operatorname{y}(x)x^{\operatorname{y}(x)-1}+(\operatorname{y}(x))^x\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))\\
\operatorname{y}'(x)&=&-\dfrac{\operatorname{y}(x)x^{\operatorname{y}(x)-1}+(\operatorname{y}(x))^x\ln(\operatorname{y}(x))}{x^{\operatorname{y}(x)}\ln x+x(\operatorname{y}(x))^{x-1}}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=&-\dfrac{yx^{y-1}+y^x\ln y}{x^{y}\ln x+xy^{x-1}}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=&- \frac{y(y^{x-1}\ln y + x^{y-1})}{x(x^{y-1}\ln x + y^{x-1})}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Take $x$ and $y$ to be separate functions and try the following;
$\frac{d}{dx}(u^{v}) = vu^{v-1}\frac{du}{dx} + u^{v}\ln{u}\frac{dv}{dx}.$

Comment: ,Why you are taking $x$ and $y$ to be separate functions?

Comment: Well, because in as much $x$ may be a separate variable, $y$ can also be a function of $x$ but with a different structure-@Debrogli